# get element by id and get element by Value xpath in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, domxpath, xpathquery

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ew-language id="en">
    <global>
        <phrase id="actiondeleted" value="Deleted">
            <child_phrase_1 id="1234" value="numbers">
                <child id="test_id" value="test_value"/>
                <child id="test_id" value="test_value_2"/>
            </child_phrase_1>
        </phrase>
    </global>
</ew-language>
```

how to get element by ID and by value so the element is unique.I tried these

```
     $parent = ($xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id']")&& $xpath->query("//*[@value='$previous_tag_value']"))->item(0);
----------------------AND THIS ONE-----------------------------------
     $parent = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id']/*@value='$previous_tag_value')"->item(0);
----------------------AND THIS ONE-----------------------------------
 $xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id' and @value='$previous_tag_value']");
```

each syntax is not working.

Comment: `//*[@id="test_id" and @value="test_value_2"]` And deal with quotes.

Comment: this XML originally contains thousands of elements can I replace  //*[@id="test_id" and @value="test_value_2"] by //*[@id="test_id" and @value="$previous_tag_value"]

Comment: `$xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id' and @value='$previous_tag_value']");`

Comment: I am not getting you

Comment: Yes, you can replace.  Forgot about quotes. I was wrong .

Comment: `$xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id' and @value='$previous_tag_value']");` but this is not even working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `//*[@id='$previous_tag_id' and @value='$previous_tag_value']` should've worked, see the demo in [eval.in](https://eval.in/383308) :

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ew-language id="en">
    <global>
        <phrase id="actiondeleted" value="Deleted">
            <child_phrase_1 id="1234" value="numbers">
                <child id="test_id" value="test_value"/>
                <child id="test_id" value="test_value_2"/>
            </child_phrase_1>
        </phrase>
    </global>
</ew-language>
XML;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$previous_tag_id = "test_id";
$previous_tag_value = "test_value_2";
$result = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$previous_tag_id' and @value='$previous_tag_value']");
foreach($result as $r)
{
    echo $doc->saveXML($r);
}
```

**output :**

```
<child id="test_id" value="test_value_2"/>
```